# How can I call (Iron)Python code from a C# app?

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

Is there a way to call Python code, using IronPython I assume, from C#? If so, how?

Comment: One of the big reasons for the C# 4.0 *dynamic* keyword.  Do you have it?  Important.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75983934/5967360

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The process is simple, especially in a C#/.NET 4 application where support for dynamic languages have been improved via usage of the `dynamic` type.  But it all ultimately depends on how you intend to use the (Iron)Python code within your application.  You could always run `ipy.exe` as a separate process and pass your source files in so they may be executed.  But you probably wanted to *host* them in your C# application.  That leaves you with many options.

1. Add a reference to the `IronPython.dll` and `Microsoft.Scripting.dll` assemblies.  You'll usually find them both in your root IronPython installation directory.
2. Add `using IronPython.Hosting;` to the top of your source and create an instance of the IronPython scripting engine using `Python.CreateEngine()`.
3. You have a couple of options from here but basically you'd create a `ScriptScope` or `ScriptSource` and store it as a `dynamic` variable.  This allows you to execute it or manipulate the scopes from C# if you choose to do so.

#### Option 1:

Using `CreateScope()` to create an empty `ScriptScope` to use directly in C# code but usable in Python sources.  You can think of these as your global variables within an instance of the interpreter.

```
dynamic scope = engine.CreateScope();
scope.Add = new Func<int, int, int>((x, y) => x + y);
Console.WriteLine(scope.Add(2, 3)); // prints 5
```

#### Option 2:

Using `Execute()` to execute any IronPython code in a string.  You can use the overload where you may pass in a `ScriptScope` to store or use variables defined in the code.

```
var theScript = @"def PrintMessage():
    print 'This is a message!'

PrintMessage()
";

// execute the script
engine.Execute(theScript);

// execute and store variables in scope
engine.Execute(@"print Add(2, 3)", scope);
// uses the `Add()` function as defined earlier in the scope
```

#### Option 3:

Using `ExecuteFile()` to execute an IronPython source file.  You can use the overload where you may pass in a `ScriptScope` to store or use variables defined in the code.

```
// execute the script
engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\path\to\script.py");

// execute and store variables in scope
engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\path\to\script.py", scope);
// variables and functions defined in the scrip are added to the scope
scope.SomeFunction();
```

#### Option 4:

Using `GetBuiltinModule()` or the `ImportModule()` extension method to create a scope containing the variables defined in said module.  Modules imported this way must be set in the search paths.

```
dynamic builtin = engine.GetBuiltinModule();
// you can store variables if you want
dynamic list = builtin.list;
dynamic itertools = engine.ImportModule("itertools");
var numbers = new[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 2 };
Console.WriteLine(builtin.str(list(itertools.chain(numbers, "foobar"))));
// prints `[1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 2, 'f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']`

// to add to the search paths
var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\path\to\modules");
engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);

// import the module
dynamic myModule = engine.ImportModule("mymodule");
```

You can do quite a lot hosting Python code in your .NET projects.  C# helps bridging that gap easier to deal with.  Combining all the options mentioned here, you can do just about anything you want.  There's of course more you can do with the classes found in the `IronPython.Hosting` namespace, but this should be more than enough to get you started.

Comment: engine = Python.CreateEngine() is also needed

Answer (score 11):

To run a function you can't call it like in Option 3 of Jeff Mercado's response (which is a great and very helpful one! But this option doesn't compile, at least on .NET 4.5). You can use ScriptScope.GetVariable to get the actual function and then you can call it like a C# function.
Use it like this:

C# code:

```
var var1,var2=...
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\test.py", scope);
dynamic testFunction = scope.GetVariable("test_func");
var result = testFunction(var1,var2);
```

Python code:

```
def test_func(var1,var2):
    ...do something...
```

Took me a while to finally figure it out, and it's quite simple.. Too bad there's no good IronPython documentation. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 7):

1) Need to install

```
Install-Package DynamicLanguageRuntime -Version 1.2.2
```

2) Need to add "Iropython.dll" using this: https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-add-references-your-visual-studio-project.cfm

3) Need to Use

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using IronPython.Runtime;
using IronPython;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting;
```

3) Need to set var

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
```