# Importing a module in .NET and then using it as an object?

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython

I have a Python module, and I'd like to be able to import parts of it like classes in C#, accessing its methods and such as .NET native as possible.

How can I accomplish this using IronPython?

Comment: I believe the question has been asked and [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7060760/650012) before on SO, if I am not mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages

You can assemble Python modules as dynamic-link libraries and then pinvoke them in any .NET application. You can find more details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I'll give this some investigation, thank you!