# Call a Python function with multiple return values from C#

Tags: c#, ironpython

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053172/how-can-i-call-ironpython-code-from-a-c-sharp-app) gives a nice overview of how to call a python function from C# using IronPython.

If our python source looks like:

```
def get_x():
    return 1
```

The basic approach is:

```
var script = @"
def get_x():
    return 1";

var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
dynamic scope = engine.CreateScope();
engine.Execute(script, scope);

var x = scope.get_x();
Console.WriteLine("x is {0}", x);
```

But what if our python source is:

```
def get_xyz():
    return 1, 2, 3
```

What is the C# syntax for handling multiple return values?

Comment: Have you tried executing that and seeing what the return value is?

Comment: No, I don't have a C# environment set up yet. I am working on the Python side and trying to help someone connect to it from C#, so I'm a bit limited right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IronPython runtime provides the result of `get_xyz()` as a [PythonTuple](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/ipy-2.7-maint/Languages/IronPython/IronPython/Runtime/PythonTuple.cs) which means it can be used as `IList`, `ICollection`, `IEnumerable<object>` ...

Because of the primarily static nature of C# there are no syntax constructs similar to python's way of unpacking tuples. Through the provided interfaces and collection APIs you could receive the values as

```
var xyz = scope.get_xyz();
int x = xyz[0];
int y = xyz[1];
int z = xyz[2];
```