# C# WPF + Python

Tags: python, c#, wpf

Can you tell me, please, what is more correct way to use Python in conjunction with C# WPF? I have come across many Python implementations and I confused about them. I can not understand the implementation of even the simplest, for example, entering a value into the Label by clicking a button using Python:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="btn1" Grid.Row="1" Width="200" Height="30" Content="Click" Click="btn1_Click"/>
    <Label x:Name="lbl1" Grid.Row="1" Width="200" Height="30" Margin="79,23,513,23" Content="Nothing..." />  
</Grid>
```

Button's code:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
            ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            var a = engine.Execute("print('hello world')");
            lbl1.Content = a;
      
    }
```

Can you tell me about IronPython or .NET Python and C# WPF + Python?

Best wishes.

Comment: I've used ironpython with wpf. My advice would be to stick with c#.

Comment: how you create this app, which I described in a question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053172/how-can-i-call-ironpython-code-from-a-c-sharp-app

Answer (score 0):

here you can find a lot of data about WPF + IronPython:
https://livebook.manning.com/book/ironpython-in-action/chapter-9/20
, you can find there examples and different uses for IronPython in c# wpf